# Execute an SBT command from a script

Tags: bash, shell, scala, sbt

**decided to start a bounty & edited out information not needed*

**I would like to run a script inside the SBT console that would run an SBT command at the end. How can this be done**

I wrote a script that allows me to execute shell commands. Typing in `sbt` then `path/to/my-script start` gives me this error: `/bin/sh: start command not found`

But `path/to/my-script sbt start` works fine

**Reason why sbt plugins (such as [these](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Community/Community-Plugins.html#system-plugins)) or a custom task won't work in this case**:

- The script is not written in scala

*quick edit*

*I would prefer to execute `start` from a script instead of using custom task/command to run my script

#### *More info below*

---

I'll explain step by step what I'd like to do (what I'm doing may sound silly to you but please read my response to Etan):

1. Type sbt in my console which will invoke the SBT console
2. Instead of typing `start`, I'd like to run a script which will perform something else that doesn't directly have anything to do with the project and then invoke `start` for me when it's done.

Being not too familiar with scripting, script can invoke `#!/bin/sh` commands, so I guess what I'm trying to do is invoke a `#!/bin/sh/<*this-sbt-console*>` command if that's possible

Even a workaround like if I can get the script to just print `start` on the terminal and invoke the `enter/return` key after it's done, would suffice

other info:

- Not using any specific framework
- SBT Version = 0.13+

Comment: Your script runs itself as a scala script with its arguments passed through? Why do you want to run this at the sbt prompt? Doesn't sbt give you ways to run your scala scripts more directly?

Comment: @EtanReisner As stated above: 1. I'm using `start` as an example 2. I'm also using that small Scala script as an example (the actual script is longer & in a different language) 3. There's a lot more going on (see 1 & 2) 4. I'd like to learn more about the Scala tools I use by getting my hands a little dirty

Comment: sbt is a build tool. yes, it has a `console` task, which lets you play in the REPL with any classes on your project's classpath and your own code, but what that has to do with getting sbt to execute bash files? I don't understand what is it you are trying to achieve here... so can you expand? BTW, when you use `path/to/my-script sbt start`, sbt has nothing to do with it... the bash file executes the scala REPL with 2 arguments ("sbt" & "start"). PS.your sample code has errors

Comment: @giladhoch if I'm inside the SBT REPL & I type `start` it will run my app. Is there a way to do this from a script? It's weird because I can run the script using `sbt start` from inside the REPL but `start` alone even though I'm already inside the REPL didn't work (see error above)

Comment: I still don't get you. why do you (think you) need sbt? the script execute the **Scala REPL**, which is **NOT** the same as the **SBT console**. so, when you type in the command line `path/to/my-script sbt start`, the shell will look at the first argument (`path/to/my-script`) and will execute it (meaning executes the **Scala REPL**) while passing the other parameters (`sbt`&`start`) as arguments. when you type `sbt` and then `path/to/my-script start`, you will invoke the **SBT console** which will except `path/to/my-script`&`start` as arguments. why would you expect the result to be the same?

Comment: @giladhoch ok, so I guess I meant the SBT console. I'll explain step by step what I'd like to do (what I'm doing may sound silly to you but please read my response to Etan): 1. type `sbt` in my console which will invoke the **SBT console** 2. Instead of typing `start`, I'd like to run a script which will perform something else that doesn't directly have to do with the project and then invoke `start` for me when it's done. -- I hope I understood your response correctly and I hope this clears everything up. Thanks

Comment: So I guess you need a [suitable sbt plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Community/Community-Plugins.html#system-plugins) like [sbt-sh](https://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh). or, if you doing something very specific, creating a custum sbt task might be a better solution.

Comment: @giladhoch Wow, thank you! Only problem I see with this is that they're all made for Scala. I'll dive into the source to figure out what's really going on but I'd really like to find a way to execute sbt commands from a regular script written in another language. I was hoping there'd be a way to tell the script that this is not a "SH" command but an "SBT command"

Comment: you could write a [`.sbtrc` file](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Best-Practices.html#sbtrc), and let sbt read & execute that file on startup.

Comment: @giladhoch hmmm.. So I'm assuming there's no clever way to interact with the SBT console without using a SBT plugin(?). Is there a way to just tell a script to write something onto the terminal and _press_ _return/enter_?

Comment: 1) Do you require the answer for a specific sbt version? Is 0.13 OK? 2) Is the `start` command defined by a framework, such as Play Framework? Or is it a pure Scala project, without a framework?

Comment: @FernandoCorreia pure scala & 0.13+ is ok

Answer (score 11):

In order to be able to execute a script and, after that script completes, proceed to execute another sbt command, one approach is to implement a custom sbt command which does the following:

1. Executes an external process supplied as its first argument, passing any additional arguments to this process.
2. Waits for the external process to finish.
3. After the external process finishes, executes another sbt command.

This is demonstrated in this `Build.scala` file:

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

// imports standard command parsing functionality
import complete.DefaultParsers._

object CommandExample extends Build {
  // Declare a project, adding new commands.
  lazy override val projects = Seq(root)
  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) settings(
    commands ++= Seq(start, customStart)
  )

  // A fake "start" command.
  def start = Command.command("start") { state =>
    println("Fake start command executed.")
    state
  }

  // A command that executes an external command before executing the "start" command. 
  // The name of the external command is the first parameter.
  // Any additional parameters are passed along to the external command.
  def customStart = Command.args("customStart", "<name>") { (state, args) =>
    if (args.length > 0) {
      val externalCommand = args.mkString(" ")
      println(s"Executing '$externalCommand'")
      externalCommand !
    }
    "start" :: state
  }
}
```

This is a sample execution:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/fernando/work/github/fernandoacorreia/so24565469/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/home/fernando/work/github/fernandoacorreia/so24565469/)
> customStart ls -la
Executing 'ls -la'
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  6 fernando fernando 4096 Jul  8 10:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 fernando fernando 4096 Jul  8 08:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 fernando fernando   95 Jul  8 10:47 build.sbt
drwxr-xr-x  8 fernando fernando 4096 Jul  8 08:58 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 fernando fernando  203 Jul  8 09:04 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 fernando fernando 1082 Jul  8 08:51 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x  3 fernando fernando 4096 Jul  8 10:51 project
-rw-r--r--  1 fernando fernando  111 Jul  8 08:51 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  3 fernando fernando 4096 Jul  8 08:57 src
drwxr-xr-x  2 fernando fernando 4096 Jul  8 10:52 target
Fake start command executed.
>
```

The external command passed as a parameter to `customStart` may be any executable command, e.g. a binary file or a shell script.

To learn more about creating commands, refer to the [Commands documentation page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html).

To learn more about executing external processes, refer to the [External Processes documentation page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html).

The complete example is available for download at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/fernandoacorreia/so24565469).

Since sbt executes the script (as a child process), that script can't execute commands on the original (parent) sbt process.

It would be possible to capture the script's output, either to `stdout` or to a file, and have the sbt command execute an arbitrary command generated by the script, but that's somewhat convoluted.

Another approach would be to invert the order of execution. Instead of having `sbt` execut the script, the script would be executed first, directly from the shell, and the script would execute the sbt command.

For instance, this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running custom script"
# Insert commands here
sbt start
```

Produces this output:

```
$ ./script 
Running custom script
[info] Loading project definition from /home/fernando/work/github/fernandoacorreia/so24565469/project
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/home/fernando/work/github/fernandoacorreia/so24565469/)
Fake start command executed.
```

Comment: Is there any way to execute `start` from a script? Would that be impossible? Or do you know of any other workarounds that don't involve running the script from a custom task/command?

Comment: If the script is running as a child process, it can't execute commands in the context of its parent process. In theory a sbt command could be created that instead of just waiting for the script to finish, would open some kind of channel that would receive messages from the script and execute them in the context of the parent process, but that is very convoluted, complex and fragile. I added more information to the question about how to invert the order of execution, which might be an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

As you say "Is there a way to just tell a script to write something onto the terminal and press return/enter?"

yes - the slightly hacky but highly effective solution is a little program called **expect**.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/

http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts

It will let you do anything you can do from the keyboard, but automatically.  It's like a macro playback engine for the UNIX command prompt.

Comment: Could you please add more detail? I tried `spawn` but that didn't work. How would you exactly simply write out `start` and execute it using expect?